# Where can I buy a 'Conjure Flame Atronach' spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to play as a Mage but some units are immune to magic. Where can I buy a 'Conjure Flame Atronach' tome?

Comment: It ended up that I found it doing the Azura's Star mission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can purchase the spell from any of the court wizards in the Jarls' castles in the major cities once your Conjuration skill is high enough (25).

Comment: I was able to purchase it from the resident wizard in Dragonsreach, Farengar Secret-Fire, in Whiterun.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest, that you join the Mightyy.. College of WinterHold.

Travel to Winterhold by carriage.., Go to the bridge, and talk to the woman, she will give you the Flame of Atronach, Magelight, or Fire BOLT spell, at a mere 30 Gold! Once your in you can learn any spell you please, and do exciting quests.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase it from:

- [Calcelmo](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Calcelmo) (at Understone Keep, Markarth)
- [Falion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falion) (resident wizard of Morthal)
- [Farengar Secret-Fire](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Farengar_Secret-Fire) (court wizard at Whiterun)
- [Madena](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Madena) (court wizard at Dawnstar)
- [Nelacar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nelacar) (living in the Frozen Hearth inn at Winterhold)
- [Phinis Gestor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Phinis_Gestor) (a mage at College of Winterhold)
- [Sybille Stentor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sybille_Stentor) (court wizard at Solitude)
- [Wuunferth the Unliving](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wuunferth_the_Unliving) (court wizard at Windhelm)
- [Wylandriah](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wylandriah) (court wizard at Riften)

You can also create the "Conjure Flame Atronach" tome at the [Atronach Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atronach_Forge) (The Midden, College of Winterhold).

Source: UESP wiki's "[Conjure Flame Atronach](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Conjure_Flame_Atronach)" article